# Best way to create form with Html.BeginForm() that should be SSL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form on a non-SSL page that I want to submit as SSL. I am creating the form using Html.BeginForm but that isn't required.
It would also be nice if I could make it configuratble, so that i could have a flag that I set so that on the dev server or on my laptop I can turn the SSL off and turn it on in the production server.

I know that I could just make the entire URL a config item but I was hoping that I could make it more flexible so I could just have a true or false setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the action attribute of the form created by Html.BeginForm.

```
<% 
   var actionURL = (Model.UseSSL ? "https://" : "http://") 
                   + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;    

   using (
          Html.BeginForm(
                         "Action", 
                         "Controller", 
                         FormMethod.Post, 
                         new { @action = actionURL }
                        )
         )
%>
```

Note the use of the Model.UseSSL flag, which should be passed to this View by its Controller.

Comment: this might be what I need. let me give it a try!!

Comment: ActionLink renders an anchor tag. Is there something that will return the url but have the same option of specifying the protocol?

Comment: I edited the post.  I believe you may be able to override the forms action itself.  If that doesn't work, you can render the form tag yourself without Html.BeginForm, in which case you can control its action setting however you like.

Comment: I ended up writing out the form element and filling in the action attribute from a string I put togeter using Request.Url.Host, ResolveUrl("~"), and a config flag to tell me whether to use http or https.

in your suggestion I think the actionURL just overrided the Action and Controller you set. Also, using PathAndQuery isn't the URL I wanted to post to, so those kindof made using BeginForm pointless even though that is what I wanted to do.
But this got me close enough.

Answer (score 3):

i know it's an old question, 
just a suggestion for a cleaner solution:

```
<form id="someLie" method="post" action="<%=Url.Action("action", "controller",new {}, YourConfigOrModel.UseSSL ? Uri.UriSchemeHttps : Uri.UriSchemeHttp) %>">
.. form elements..
</form>
```

this will render an absolute path containing the https://.. or a regular relative one for http

Comment: I've tried something similar to this and I lost the unobtrusive validation for the form.